# How to get String value in Google Sheet Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

This is my code. I want to make tic toc toe game
I'm stuck at check value in cell. now I want to use for loop to check cell by cell. I don't know how to write it. Pls help me. TT

```
function onEdit(e) {



var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = activeSheet.getRange("B2:D4");
  var data = cell.getValues();
  var data1 = data[2][2];
  
  
  
  if(cell.getValues !== [["","",""],["","",""],["","",""]]){
  Logger.log(cell.getValues());
  Logger.log(data1)
  for (var i = 2; i < 5; i++)
  {
    Logger.log("for1");
    for (var j = 2; j < 5; j++)
    {
      Logger.log("for2");
      if(data[i][j] == "X")
      {
        Logger.log("D")
        activeSheet.getRange("H2").setValue("Playing");
      }else
      {
        activeSheet.getRange("H2").setValues("");
        Logger.log("F")
        Logger.log(data1)
        
      }
    }
  }
} 

}
```

Comment: `cell.getValues` is not a function. `cell.getValues()` is a function

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate your code and found some issues.

1. Array comparison - Comparing array with another array will not work, you have to either compare each element or convert the array into string by using JSON.stringify(array). ***See example 1 below***.
2. In your `for (var i = 2; i < 5; i++)` and `for (var j = 2; j < 5; j++)`, this will prompt index out of bounds once it reached 3, 4. The reason for this is the array in `var data = cell.getValues()` always start at zero. Instead you could use the array size to prevent error. ***See example 2 below.***
3. setValues can only accept 2 dimensional arrays. See [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues).
4. if else statement - The else statement will override the value of `H2` if the next element in your array is not X.

**example 1:**

```
if(JSON.stringify(data) != "[[\"\",\"\",\"\"],[\"\",\"\",\"\"],[\"\",\"\",\"\"]]"){

}
```

**example 2:**

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
  for (var j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++)
  {
  //some statement
  }
}
```

This will print every value in tictactoe Range:

**Code:**

```
function tictactoe(e) {
  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = activeSheet.getRange("B2:D4");
  var data = cell.getValues();
  var a1 = ['B', 'C', 'D'];
  if(JSON.stringify(data) != "[[\"\",\"\",\"\"],[\"\",\"\",\"\"],[\"\",\"\",\"\"]]"){
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        var column = i+2;
        for (var j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++)
        {
          Logger.log("Value in " + a1[j] + (column) +" : "+ data[i][j]);
        }
    }
  } 
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Additional info:** You can get the A1 notation of the range being populated/edited by using `e.range.getA1Notation();`